# `lmer` giving wrong number of random effects groups?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am running the follow model:

```
model <- lmer(phq4 ~ week + (1|PID), data = merged, 
              na.action = na.omit)
```

PID is the participant ID for 229 participants. There are 2188 rows altogether. When I run:

```
unique(merged$PID)
```

the output is 229, so I know all 229 PIDs are there.

However, the summary(lmer) of my model says

```
Number of obs: 2188, groups:  PID, 115
```

Groups:PID should equal 229.

Any idea why lmer is specifying the wrong number of groups for my random effect variable?

Comment: how about `length(levels(factor(merged$PID)))` ?  same as `unique(merged$PID)` ? My hunch is there is a type conversion issue. It's also suspicious that the output has also exactly half the number of levels.

Comment: Is this a growth model (longitudinal design?). If so, the `na.omit` might be removing people that you don't want removed. i.e., the key to growth models is that it can handle not having data at all time points for each participant